# How to get the mac address of BLE device in code behind in Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm connecting my Bluetooth BLE device in background. So I need to get the Bluetooth mac address in my code behind just like how we are displaying the mac address in our XAML.

```
ListView x:Name="lv" ItemSelected="lv_ItemSelected" BackgroundColor="White" SeparatorColor="Aqua"> 
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding NativeDevice.Address}"/>
                                <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding NativeDevice.Name}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

so in our xaml I'm able to get the mac address in NativeDevice.Address. So same way I need to get it in my xaml.cs. I am able to get the mac address by following this approach

```
var vailditems = adapter.DiscoveredDevices.Where(i => i.NativeDevice.ToString()
```

But this is not good approach I need to get the mac address in NativeDevice.Address just like my xaml. I tried this approach but it is giving the address as null.

```
public class NativeDevice
        {
            
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
        }
NativeDevice V = new NativeDevice();

                    Baddress = V.Address;
```

For your information the mac address is accessible in IDevice interface which is predefined. So in the IDevice interface I need to access the object NativeDevice. This is the interface.

```
public interface IDevice : IDisposable
{
   
    Guid Id { get; }
   
    string Name { get; }
   
    int Rssi { get; }
   
    object NativeDevice { get; }
   
    DeviceState State { get; }
    
    IList<AdvertisementRecord> AdvertisementRecords { get; }

    
   
    Task<IService> GetServiceAsync(Guid id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    
    Task<IList<IService>> GetServicesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
   
    Task<bool> UpdateRssiAsync();
}
```

So I need to access the interface and get the NativeDevice.address in code behind. And I will be removing the XAML part so I don't need the mac address from itemsource of ListView aswell. [This is the github plugin](https://github.com/didourebai/BLEPluginDemo)  I have used to implement my BLE app if you want to have a look at my full source code.This is my code where I'm accessing the BLE object.

```
public IDevice device;
var obj = device.NativeDevice;
```

Where the code for IDevice interface is

```
public interface IDevice : IDisposable
{
   
    Guid Id { get; }
   
    string Name { get; }
  Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Contracts.IDevice.UpdateRssiAsync.
    int Rssi { get; }
   
    DeviceState State { get; }
   
     object NativeDevice { get; }
    Task<IList<IService>> GetServicesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
   
    Task<int> RequestMtuAsync(int requestValue);
  
    Task<bool> UpdateRssiAsync();
}
```

I don't have any clue regarding this. Any suggestions?

Comment: either [cast it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151662/getting-native-device-information-from-bluetoothle-device) to the correct type or [use reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129421/get-property-of-generic-class) to get the values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting the address property in the code behind you need to do dependency service. So first create an interface called INativeDevice this is the code for the interface

```
public interface INativeDevice
    {
        //new object NativeDevice { get; }
        //void getaddress();
        NativeDevice ConvertToNative(object device);
    }
```

secondly create a class in android specific project called NativeDeviceConverter this is the code

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(NativeDeviceConverter))]
namespace Workshop.Droid.Injected
{
   public class NativeDeviceConverter:INativeDevice
    {
       
        public NativeDevice ConvertToNative(object device)
        {
            var dev = device as Device;
            if (dev != null)
                return new NativeDevice { Name = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dev.BluetoothDevice.Name) ? dev.BluetoothDevice.Name : string.Empty, Address = dev.BluetoothDevice.Address };
            else
                return new NativeDevice();
        }
    }
}
```

After this write this code in your code behind to fetch the Address of your Bluetooth device

```
 NativeDeviceAdd = DependencyService.Get<INativeDevice>().ConvertToNative(a.Device);
                    PropertyInfo propInfo = NativeDeviceAdd.GetType().GetProperty("Address");
                     BLEaddressnew = (string)propInfo.GetValue(NativeDeviceAdd, null);
```

So with this Address you can do scan operation in background and filter your discovered device.

Answer (score 5):

```
// this assumes that you already have the BLE object
// from the BLE plugin
var obj = myBLEobject.NativeDevice;
// we want the "Address" property
PropertyInfo propInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Address"); 
string address = (string)propInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
```

Comment: this is simple solution and its work for me but not sure is it good to use reflection in mobile env ?